# SQLite3 Table Only Holds 1 Row

Tags: javascript, sql, node-sqlite3

So, I have 2 tables, that I've added per the documentation, but something weird happens whenever I try to add a row to them. The data is written into the .db file, but whenever I query it, it only returns the first row. I can still update, and read these rows normally, but any data I write to them, just doesn't update the table. It's only the first row that get's written.

I've looked over all my statements, and I know they're right, since the first statement adds it to the table, but the second doesn't. I'm using the base configuration of sqlite3 from npm, per the docs, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I don't have any errors, and the expected result, is that I'm able to add as many rows as I can

```
db.serialize(function() {
 db.run("CREATE TABLE users (userId int, user varchar(255))");
 db.run("CREATE TABLE notes (userId int, uuid varchar(50), name varchar(255), noteData varchar(1024), file BLOB(21845))")
});

db.run("INSERT INTO users (userId, user) VALUES (0, 'User')")
db.run(`INSERT INTO notes (userId, uuid, name, noteData) VALUES (0, 'uuid', 'First Note','This will be readable.')`)

//This statement will add the data to the file, but the query won't read it.
db.run(`INSERT INTO notes (userId, uuid, name, noteData) VALUES (1, 'uuid2', 'First Note','This will not show.')`)
db.get("SELECT * FROM notes",[],(err,row)=>{console.log(row)})
```

Also, this is not an asynchronous problem. In the example, I added the last line, but it's not actually in my code. I'm requesting it minutes later, and I can confirm the text is in the database, it just decides not to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `db.all()`. `db.get()` only returns the first row.